# I want to insert row in table every 5 min with cron job

Tags: php, database, cron

I am trying to run a cron job every 5 minute that will insert a new row into a specific table . I added the path to the test.php file to execute it every 5 minute. The test.php looks like this:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$auto=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `user`");
while($load=mysqli_fetch_assoc($auto))
{
 $myid=$load['uname'];
 $sponsarid=$load['under_userid'];
 $insert=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `test`(`uname`,`sponsorid`) VALUES 
 ('$myid','$sponsarid')");
}
?>
```

This script works fine when I just write the path directly in the browser, but it doesn't run automatically.

I am using godaddy server and the command is /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/[user name]/public_html/panel/auto_load/test.php

I tried this mail function with my insert query to test and i receive mail every 5 min but rows not inserted in table.

```
<?php
    $to = "abc@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Cronjob";
    $txt = " If you get this mail thats mean your code works fine. ";
    $headers = "From:xyz@gmail.com";
    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers); 
 ?>
```

Comment: we need atleast to know which OS you are coding in and the cron file

Comment: I am using godaddy server and the command  is   /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/[user name]/public_html/panel/auto_load/test.php

Comment: please edit your question with the informations instead of writing them in the comment

Comment: That `include` should be a `require`, because your script won’t be able to do anything if it doesn’t get a database connection to begin with. Change that, and see if you get errors in the log regarding that, saying it can’t find `connection.php`. If you implemented the cron in a way that the script gets run via CLI, then the configuration regarding `include_path` might simply be different. Try and make that `./connection.php` to explicitly refer to the current directory, so that the `include_path` setting becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If the code runs fine from within a browser, from what I know you should add the following as first line to execute it via command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```